# Calculate the number of occurrences of letters, and put the dictionaries in the list

Tags: scala

I'm trying to count occurences of letters in the Stream of strings, and then put maps for each string ( "letter"-> count) in the List.

```
def checksum(ipt: Stream[String]) =  ipt.foldLeft(List(Map("x"->1)))( (n: 
List[Map[String, Int]], m: String)  => n ++ 
m.split("").groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toMap)
```

It gives problem:

```
 Expression of type List[Equals] doesn't conform to expected type List[Map[String, Int]]
```

What's wrong? Like there is no problem with doing it for each string:

```
 def checksum(ipt: Stream[String]) =  ipt.foreach( (m: String)  => println(m.split("").groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)))
```

It gives something like that on

```
val s = "bababc"
val d = "abbcde"
checksum(List(s,d).toStream)
out: 
Map(b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 1)
Map(e -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1, d -> 1)
```

But how do i stash all this maps in the List now? I can't use vars and need to do it in one expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need a map for each string, you can achieve it with a map function over the first stream as follows:

```
 def checksums(ipt: Stream[String]): Stream[Map[Char, Int]] = {
    ipt.map(checksum)
 }

 def checksum(ipt: String): Map[Char, Int] = ipt.foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int]) { case (acc, ch) =>
     acc.get(ch) match {
        case Some(q) => acc + (ch -> (q + 1))
        case None => acc + (ch -> 1)
     }
 }
```

---

Going back to your code, the operator to add an element to a List is :+, not ++.

++ is used to concatenate lists.

So you can fix your code like this:

```
def checksumFixed(ipt: Stream[String]) = {
    ipt.foldLeft(List(Map("x"->1))) { (n: List[Map[String, Int]], m: String) =>
      n :+ m.split("").groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
    }
  }
```